# How to properly call singleton implementation

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, singleton

I have got this singleton implementation in MVC project:

```
public sealed class Singleton<T> where T : class {
    private static volatile T _instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();
    static Singleton() {}

    public static T Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null)
                lock (_lock) {
                    if (_instance == null) {
                        ConstructorInfo constructor = null;
                        try {
                            // Binding flags exclude public constructors.
                            constructor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[0], null);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception) {
                            throw new SingletonException(exception);
                        }
                        if (constructor == null || constructor.IsAssembly) // Also exclude internal constructors.
                            throw new SingletonException(string.Format("A private or protected constructor is missing for '{0}'.", typeof(T).Name));
                        _instance = (T)constructor.Invoke(null);
                    }
                }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a controller and this Instance method

```
    public static Controller Instance {
        get { return Singleton<Controller>.Instance; }
    }
```

In controller constructor I want to load something like this

```
    private Controller() {
       int id = Controller.Instance.SqlManager.GetId();
    }
```

This gives me a loop of course and I don't know how to escape from this.

Comment: why don;t you just do `private Controller() {
       int id = SqlManager.GetId();
    }`

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the class constructor to be `private` and invoking the constructor via reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO access via `Controller.Instance` is for the clients of `Controller`, internally you should use the controller fields and methods directly, you don't need to know whether your class is being used as a singleton or not.